# Not reaching all branches of a case statement

Tags: arduino, case

My project is a dead bolt that uses RF key fob.  It checks for unlock or lock button press and also checks if the lock is locked or not.  I use a case statement for the various choices.  I think for some reason the lock state isn't changing because I am only getting cases 2 and 4.

I watered down the output actions to light blinks for each case (case 1 blinks once case 2 twice etc..)

After each case executes it changes the Boolean lock state (locked = true)

Code

```
/*
This code will open a deadbolt
 with RF remote or buttons and
 knows the position of the lock
 based on last action

 12 RF/Button lock
 13 RF/Button unlock
 10 button lock
 11 button unlock


 8 Buzzer
 9 Servo

 A0 Servo location

 4 LED lock
 5 LED unlock

 */
const int lockrf = 12; //input to lock rf
const int ulockrf = 13; //input to unlock rf
const int butlock = 10; // button lock
const int butulock = 11; // button unlock
const int ulockled = 4; //led in lock button
const int lockled = 2; //led in ulock button


#include <Servo.h>
boolean lockstate = true;

void setup()
{
  Servo deadbolt;

  deadbolt.attach(9);
  pinMode(butlock,INPUT);
  pinMode(butulock,INPUT);
  pinMode(ulockrf,INPUT);
  pinMode(lockrf,INPUT);

  pinMode(ulockled,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lockled,OUTPUT);

}
void loop()
{
  //variables for code


  int lockdeg = 0;
  int ulockdeg = 90;


  int lock_case = 0;

  digitalWrite(ulockled,LOW);
  digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);



  if (digitalRead(lockrf)==HIGH || digitalRead(butlock)==HIGH && lockstate == true ) // locked press lock
  {
    lock_case=1;
  }

  if (digitalRead(lockrf)==HIGH || digitalRead(butlock)==HIGH && lockstate == false) // ulocked press lock
  {
    lock_case=2;
  }
  if (digitalRead(ulockrf)==HIGH || digitalRead(butulock)==HIGH && lockstate == true) // locked press ulock
  {
    lock_case=3;
  }

  if (digitalRead(ulockrf)==HIGH || digitalRead(butulock)==HIGH && lockstate == false) // ulocked press ulock
  {
    lock_case=4;
  }

  switch(lock_case)
  {
  case 1:
    {

      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);

      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);

      delay(10);
      lockstate=true;
      break;
    }
   case 2:
    {
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);

      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);

      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      lockstate=true;
      break;
    }
  case 3:
    {
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);

      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);


      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      lockstate=false;
      break;
    }
  case 4:
    {
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);

      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);


      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(lockled,HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(ulockled,LOW);

      delay(10);
      lockstate=false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed code formatting.  Simplified the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is operator precedence.  Arduino follows C-language precedence, in which && is evaluated before ||.  For example, this means that your first if statement is evaluated as if you had parentheses like so:

```
digitalRead(lockrf)==HIGH || 
    (digitalRead(butlock)==HIGH && lockstate == true)
```

What happens here is that if lockrf is high, *both* of the first two if statements are true, so you first set lock_case to 1, then to 2.  You get a similar effect when ulockrf is high.  This is why you get only cases 2 and 4.

To fix this, add parentheses to disambiguate:

```
if ((digitalRead(lockrf)==HIGH || digitalRead(butlock)==HIGH)
    && lockstate == true )
```

Good programming practice suggests using parentheses if there's any doubt.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first arduino project so I'm still learning the syntax and what not.